# Mongoose OpenShift Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I'm building an application on openShift using nodejs and mongodb. I'm also using mongoose and try to connect with this code

```
var url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL;
    var db = mongoose.connect(
        url,
        function(err) {
            console.log("Error loading the db...");
        });
```

Checking on the openshift logs I can see that it gives me the error message. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You need to concatenate the `process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME` as well i.e. `var url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;`

Comment: It gives me the same error message

Comment: Which mongoose version are you using?

Comment: the last I think.. I took the lib using `npm install mongoose`

Comment: Can you please confirm the actual version number by either inspecting your packages.json file or by `npm view mongoose versions`? The reason why I'm asking is because the mongoose connect method with a callback does not work with newer Mongoose versions (3.X). Rather try `mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { ... });`

Comment: the version is 3.8.15, so what should I try? Using the local mongodb the method connect works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the following pattern:

**server.js**

```
// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        
var app        = express();                 
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');

var url = '127.0.0.1:27017/' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;

// if OPENSHIFT env variables are present, use the available connection info:
if (process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL) {
    url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

// Connect to mongodb
var connect = function () {
    mongoose.connect(url);
};
connect();

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(error){
    console.log("Error loading the db - "+ error);
});

db.on('disconnected', connect);
```

Comment: I also suffered from the problem. I want to bring out the reason why I suffer this because I try to connect the other database. so the parameter ```process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME``` is very important.